# Backspace is not clearing the field in mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the input box which allows only numeric.In chrome and firefox it allows only numeric but can't delete the number in using backspace in mozilla.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#price').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
   event.preventDefault();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='price'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `keypress` only detects the printable keys, **but the current version of Mozilla is able to detect backspace** as well. Use the `keydown` event instead.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').keydown(function(event) {
    console.log(event.which);
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='price'>
```

**Another approach** **Important!**

Using above approach you will also have to check for other special keys like arrow keys and delete keys, not to mention if `.` is placed correctly and only once.

Another approach could be to simply remove non-numeric characters from the string on `keyup`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').keyup(function(event) {
     this.value = this.value.replace( /[^0-9.]/g, "" );
     this.value = this.value.split(".").reduce((a,b,i)=> i > 1 ? a+b : a+"."+b );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='price'>
```

Comment: I think this code having some issue with keycode == 8, check once.

Comment: @Vinoth I am not using keypress event, using keydown instead.

Comment: @gurvinder, before you are using key down, Now your answer is same as mine.

Comment: @Vinoth How is my answer same as yours? Even though my second approach uses `keyup`, the code inside `keyup` event is totally different from yours.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you using a wrong way to avoid backspace. There backspace 8 as key code so you have avoided this in prevent default.use this code instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#price').keypress(function(event) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && event.which != 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

keypress event not working in firefox. you can use `keyup` or `keydown` event it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#price').keyup(function(event) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && event.which != 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Now your answer is essentially same as mine.